# How do I create a windowless C# app that resides in the tray?

Tags: c#, windowless

As question says, How do I create such an app ? How do I make it windowless and make it reside in the system tray (bottom right) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to start minimized, just do a `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized` before showing the window, and remove the code in `NotifyIcon.DoubleClick` that maximizes it.

Answer (score 2):

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon();
        icon.Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Application;
        icon.Click += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Bye!"); icon.Visible = false; Application.Exit(); };
        icon.Visible = true;
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```